# What is this electrical fixture above a natural gas fired forced air furnace?

Tags: wiring, furnace, smoke-detectors

While visiting my mother-in-law, we wanted to get the smoke detector situation in her house up to par (this is in Massachusetts, we're from Europe, though). She has a natural gas fired forced air furnace in her basement; it blows warm air directly into various rooms instead of using radiators.

Above the furnace, we found the following fixture:

[image: eviscerated ceiling fixture connected to two wire ducts]

(Sorry for the overexposure, the lighting situation is not quite optimal there.)

To me, it looks a bit like the eviscerated remains of a smoke detector. What throws me off, though, is that it has two wire conduits leading to it: the bx conduit leads to a small box attached to the furnace, the smooth conduit leads directly to the breaker box. I'm used to smoke detectors running on an independent 9V battery, with no conduits. I'm also sure it's not just a broken light fixture, given the text on it says it's an "alarm". (The text also refers to detailed instructions on the inside of the base of the alarm, but the base is nowhere to be found.)

What is is thing and what would need to be done to repair it?

Comment: Some terminology used in the US: The tubing carrying wires is called conduit.  Ducts or duct work carry the air from the furnace air handler to the various rooms. This type of central heating is called a natural gas fired forced air furnace.

Comment: Jim I thought about mentioning the conduit or wire type bx, ac or mc. This might help the OP in the future. +

Comment: @JimStewart & EdBeal I edited my question to hopefully get the terminology right, thanks!

Comment: It's fairly common to have a **heat detector** right above the furnace that will shut the furnace down when activated. Why in heck someone removed it is beyond me. Heat rather than smoke is used to reduce false triggering in that application. If something goes horribly wrong and the temperature above the furnace shoots up, you want it shut down. The base for one can be similar to or the same as the base for a related smoke detector.

Comment: I agree with the heat or thermal and I have not seen them fail like the smoke and co do especially if a dusty area.

Comment: Great job with both the original post and the edit, BTW! And don't worry about your pic, that's definitely one of the better ones we get posted here!

Comment: Detectors are generally manufactured either for connection to AC power (with battery backup), or powered exclusively by battery. It's not unlikely there's a mix of those types in a particular home. As has been mentioned, an option, available primarily on types which are intended for use with AC power, is to have an additional wire used to interconnect the devices, so that if one goes off, then all interconnected alarms go off. Such interconnected devices are more commonly used where the alarms may be a significant distance apart where one going off might not be loud enough to wake people.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I've seen those removed when the furnace was replaced/upgraded and the new furnace was not compatible with the existing detector. Installing a new detector from scratch could be cheaper/easier than removing the old wiring.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the rich and detailed input. We'll install brand new battery-based CO/smoke detectors everywhere in the house, but with the furnace thing, we'll try to convince my MIL to get a contractor involved, given its connected directly to the furnace and the mains. I'm still holding back on accepting an answer since the current going theory (it's a heat detector), if true, doesn't fit either answer well.

Answer (score 15):

That looks like it was part of a whole house smoke detector system.

Smoke detectors do have a limited life and when they start failing folks just pull them out.

Since the detector was close to the furnace it could have been smoke , carbon monoxide or both. I would see if the other detectors in the home work and in any case get replacements that are compatible with the others. You may find that multiple units may not be functioning.

On several jobs I have had to replace every smoke detector only the thermal detectors were still functional. In some cases I could get the same or similar model in other cases I had to replace the bases as the new models did not fit but used the same wiring.

You may be able to get more info off of the ring that is still there but getting a complete head will help you find compatible units.

Comment: I think Ed's on the right track. This is just the base plate for a smoke/CO detector. The wiring seems to indicate an interconnected model (two power wires and one data wire).

You may be able to replace it with almost any interconnected unit that's compatible with the others in your home. Just unscrew the base plate to remove it and mount a new one.

Comment: Thanks, @isherwood, the weird thing is, all the other detectors in the home are battery based (and yes, they are all dead as a doorknob, but at least with that type of detector, I feel more comfortable dealing with). Maybe the wired thing was part of a former, larger system, or maybe it's different from the others because it got its data directly from the furnace? I'll see if I can find more info.

Comment: Well, if the wiring is there it makes sense to upgrade all of them to an interconnected set.

Comment: Alexander, your local hardware store will carry brands that have smoke and smoke-CO units that are compatible within the brand. They come with the mounting ring. Look around the house to find other junction boxes with or without the white ring. If there's red wire with the black & white, it's almost certain to be for an alarm and the red wire is what interconnects them. If you need help confirming this or wiring it up, just post another question here.

Comment: @P2000 Thanks, good idea, but this is literally the only unit in the home thus wired. Therefore, I'm currently going with Ecnerwal's hypothesis that this was actually a heat detector specifically for the furnace (its location is directly above the furnace). I've searched the entire place for parts which might have belonged to it, coming up empty. Maybe the selection of heat detectors is small enough so that I can find the correct replacement.

Comment: I wonder if the battery units are newer, replacing some units from a wired system, and that this one wasn't tidied up when the others were, as it's in the basement out of sight.

Comment: @chris h that would be my guess many states have required smoke detector systems for 20 years on new builds.  I know in my state I usually get a call when the owners start having problems or find the extra wire in a box that was converted to a light.

Comment: @EdBeal Not being a builder I'm not sure if the rules are the same this side of the Atlantic, but I've just replaced a pair of wired units for a relative.  I should do mine as they're 20 years old and eat backup batteries faster than battery-only alarms, but they work, as tested by burnt toast every so often.  20-ish year old houses in both cases

Comment: If your home is some what clean (dust free) they last longer when dust collects in the ion chamber that kills them. 20 year old is up there, new ones battery only will last 10 years due to newer electronics. But the battery is not replaceable you end up changing the battery in the remote though or for the interlinked wireless I think a 6 pack was 150.00 the last set I purchased. Same as the wired ones if 1 goes they all go but the remote can silence them, handy for burnt toast early in the morning.

Comment: You wouldn't put a CO or combo alarm right next to the furnace...too many false positives. Mounting instructions state explicitly to put them away from  gas-burning appliances.

Comment: @mmathis Nonsense - if your CO detector goes off next to the furnace then something is broken and needs to be fixed.  I always have a CO/combo detector in the furnace room (and everywhere else in the house) and it never goes off, nor should it.  A furnace should make zero smoke and 100% of the CO should be going outside.  If either of these is not true, you have a big problem.

Comment: @j... I just looked up the 1/2 life of americium-241 it was 432 years. But dust building up in the ionizing chamber was the common life limiting problem, at one point in my career I was cleaning and calibrating ionizing detectors for a hospital. I believe it was a 10 year cycle but that has been over 20 years ago so I may be wrong on the cycle. It was rare after putting them in a fixture and blasting them that they usually met the requirements it was rare the chamber needed adjustments after the cleaning.

Comment: @EdBeal You're right, I'm an idiot - working on too many things today.

Comment: @J... while you may not have had any problems, the instructions are explicit: "Do not mount... Closer than 15 feet (4.6 meters) from a furnace or other fuel
burning heat source, or fuel burning appliances like a water heater. OR Within 5 feet (1.5 meters) of any cooking appliance". See e.g., https://www.firstalertstore.com/store/images/pdf/CO600-First_Alert_Basic_Plug-In_Carbon_Monoxide_Alarm.pdf, https://www.firstalertstore.com/store/images/pdf/First-Alert-CO710-Manual.pdf (20 feet from furnaces in this case), and others.

Comment: @mmathis A cooking appliance (like a gas stove) I can understand because that will always produce some CO that is released into the building envelope, but furnaces and water heaters should not be leaking CO.  Maybe old mid-efficiency models would be more prone to CO not always going up the (open) chimney, but even then I'd consider it a defect that should be corrected.  High efficiency furnaces and condensing water heaters should be 100% ducted outdoors.  I've used CO detectors in furnace rooms of both types (mid/high) for years and have had zero false positives.

Comment: Everyone is talking about "interconnected" smoke detectors, but OP clearly states one of the cables is connected to the furnace.  There is a comment to the question stating that there was probably a heat detector here connected to a furnace shutoff.  That seems most likely.    A combination smoke/CO/NG detector should go elsewhere in the room, not directly above the furnace.  If there is wiring for interconnected detectors, you should certainly buy compatible ones to take advantage of the wiring but according to OP that's not what we have here.

Comment: @J I also have a smoke/CO/NG detector about 10 ft away from my boiler and water heater.  It has a level reading and it is always exactly 0.  I agree with you that putting one near your boiler is a good idea and that any non-zero reading is not a false alarm.  OTOH, the instructions do say "15 feet" which is not very far, but OP says this is directly above the furnace.  So really more suitably a heat detector with boiler cutoff switch.

Answer (score 7):

I have 4 First Alert smoke and CO detectors in my home that are all interconnected and are model SC9120B. The orange wire does the connecting. The sockets look exactly like the one in your photo. They make heat, smoke, CO, and combinations of these controls. They have a life expectancy of 10 years and are warranted for that long.

Comment: They often have a sticker/plate that shows the date of manufacture or date they "expire". My house is 12 years old and I just replaced them all 2 years ago. If the detector doesn't have this info, it's probably way older than that, and in need of replacement.